# External application closes when the JFrame is closed

Tags: java, ubuntu, jframe

I have written a java program to open a external application when I click a button.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

When I click the button relevant command will be passed to the exec argument, eg.in windows

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
```

The button is added on `JFrame`.This code is working fine in both windows and ubuntu (if correct command is passed). But in Ubuntu if I open a external application and then I close the `JFrame` the external application also closed with the `JFrame`. but i need to keep the external application open.even jframe is closed(like windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call external application from java application then, JAVA application is a parent process and external application will be child process. If you check the process status in ubuntu after starting external application then it will show you both processes with diffrent pids.
Now when JVM starts external application (as a new thread) it will be executing there till the parent is alive when you close the java application it will close all the child processes too.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object. You can use that to kill the external application:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.destory();
```

Edit:

If your purpose is to keep the started external application running after you close the Java program, you should start it with the Windows command `start`. To get more help on how to use this, in a command window type this:

```
start /?
```

Comment: actually i need to keep the external application open.even jframe is closed

Comment: actually i need to do it in Ubuntu.Not in windows.In windows this happen perfectly(i can open the external application by clicking a button and keep the application open even though j frame is closed)